# How to dump a process into process.log and display it in unix?

Tags: unix

how to dump a process?
i know how to dump a file/directory but dont know how to dump a process
Basically,i want to dump all user processes into a file called process.log

Comment: So do you want to see all process names running in server?

Comment: yes first dump to a file and then display do u know the command for doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something along the lines of:

```
ps aux > processes.log
```

Above is just a simple terminal command to store information about the active processes.

Comment: no im searching for a command which should dump all user processes to a file called "process.log". and then display it